# Easiest way to add PayPal to existing Stripe billing flow

Tags: paypal, stripe-payments, paypal-subscriptions

I have an educational website that uses 'Stripe Connect' to accept payments from students, and split the payments between myself (the platform provider) and the teachers (content-creators).

Payments to teachers are currently handled through Stripe.  Whenever a student purchases content, the teacher automatically receives the payment directly into their Stripe account.  I retain a portion of the transaction directly into my Stripe account.  It's an easy system and works nicely.

The problem is that students want to pay with PayPal.

So, I would like to add PayPal as a payment option for students, without forcing content-creators to connect two separate accounts--one for when viewers pay with PayPal, and another for when viewers pay with Stripe.  The only idea I have so far, is to deposit all PayPal payments to one PayPal account, then manually "payout" teachers into their Stripe accounts every week.

But is there an automated way to do this?  Stripe says they don't accept payments from PayPal.

Any ideas/help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: If you want to accept payments and subscriptions with PayPal and many other payment methods through Stripe, check out https://easypie.shop - Shopping, Payment and Subscription Terminal

Answer (score 1):

Adaptive payments does support chained payments, as Andrew says in his answer; it would work very much like what you describe having set up with Stripe.

However, this will not meet your requirements of having both PayPal and Stripe payments arrive in a single teacher account. Unfortunately, Stripe & PayPal see each other as competitors and to my knowledge neither one has built a tidy product to consolidate "their" payments into the other company's account.

If you are willing to move away from Stripe, PayPal does provide many solutions that consolidate "raw" credit card payments and PayPal account payments into a single receiver account, including through Adaptive Payments as cited by Andrew.

I would add that Braintree, having been purchased by PayPal, provides perhaps the most Stripe-like integration for a product that would accomplish this goal. However, I do not believe that the Braintree SDK will do the chained payments for you; you might have to do some work to make that happen on your end (take the first payment, then calculate and make payouts either weekly as you mentioned or per-incoming-transaction).

A couple other things to think about: if you split some payments into delayed fulfillment but others are chained inside one payments provider you will need to support two very different flows; you may find it easier (for both you and your content providers) to select one model and run everything through that model.

Also, instead of payments going to you & then chained to the content providers you could have payments to go directly to the content providers and then trigger billing (either invoicing or automatically collected via recurring payments) from the content providers to you for your cut.

The best pattern depends largely upon how you want the legal & financial responsibilities to lie: are you providing the good or service and people are paying you for it, making you like a retail store or distributor for producers? Or are content providers providing the good or service being paid for to the students, and you are like a marketplace/facilitator/advertising venue? This question becomes significant as soon as someone is unsatisfied with something they have bought :).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Adaptive Payments](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/gs_AdaptivePayments/) platform with PayPal to split payments just like you're doing with Stripe.  Specifically, you'd use the [Pay API](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/Pay_API_Operation/) setup as a [chained payment](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/ht_ap-basicChainedPayment-curl-etc/) with a secondary receiver.

If you happen to be working with PHP my [class library for PayPal](http://www.angelleye.com/product/php-class-library-paypal/) will make all of the API calls very simple for you.